# Sending logs from docker container to FluentD

Tags: docker, fluentd, docker-container

I have a Docker container and I am sending logs from the docker container to FluentD. Now, I use the FluentD logging driver, but I am having a doubt. On the documentation (link: https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/overview/#/etw-logging-driver-options) it says, the maximum size of the FluentD buffer limit is 8MB, but, I want to know how does it exactly function?

1. Are the logs from Docker container stored in this buffer and then FluentD reads this file?
2. Also, where exactly is this file stored on my system and how can I view it?
3. If the file size exceeds 8MB, what happens?

Comment: If you have another question, ask a new question rather than editing existing ones.

Answer (score 3):

The buffer is [an in memory byte array](https://github.com/fluent/fluent-logger-golang/blob/e4d9d30c15bac2108920d9e0ec4edcef3ece0907/fluent/fluent.go#L45) so no files are involved.

The default actually looks like 1MB (1024*1024) [as Docker supplies this value](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/48569e0a35934c566b60b99c5c40ac13df517cac/daemon/logger/fluentd/fluentd.go#L33) rather than relying on the [golang fluentd modules default of 8MB](https://github.com/fluent/fluent-logger-golang/blob/e4d9d30c15bac2108920d9e0ec4edcef3ece0907/fluent/fluent.go#L22).

When the buffer [is full, it is flushed](https://github.com/fluent/fluent-logger-golang/blob/e4d9d30c15bac2108920d9e0ec4edcef3ece0907/fluent/fluent.go#L174-L176).

Comment: then, why does the website mentions that it's 8MB?

Comment: [Not sure](https://github.com/docker/docker/commit/13086f387b28ceea5aff5924e430f41608884a9b).